# What kind of mechanism does blog softwares like wordpress deal with the html inside a entry content?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

What kind of mechanism does blog softwares like wordpress deal with the html inside a entry content?

I want to know:

- How does it display pictures and links in a blog entry? Is the content of a blog entry in HTML?
- When it displays entry list on the index page, how does it make a summary/digest of each entry without breaking the HTML tags inside the summary/digest? Because if I only get first few character in a blog entry content/summary, there will be possibilities to break some tags, leaving only the open tag. For example: `Hello world!<h1> Hello worl...`
- How does it escape dangerous tags/scripts inside the HTML of blog entries?

Answer (score 0):

> How does it display pictures and links in a blog entry? Is the content of a blog entry in HTML?

Yes.  Plain old HTML.

> When it displays entry list on the index page, how does it make a summary/digest of each entry without breaking the HTML tags inside the summary/digest?

Typically it will run through text through a PHP function (strip_tags() ) that strips out the HTML tags and just leaves the text behind.  Alternately/Additionally you can enter an excerpt for any post and use the_excerpt() function to return just that.  Excerpts have tags stripped by default.

> How does it escape dangerous tags/scripts inside the HTML of blog entries?

WordPress has built in functions to sanitize data and those fire automatically on $wpdb->insert and $wpdb->update.  [For much more information and detail, read the WP Codex entry for this.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering all my questions